# How come there are still two Koreas?

Tags: north-korea, south-korea, cold-war

How come there are still two Koreas while the other divisions created by the Cold War  have ended? Do the people of Korea want the division to continue?

Comment: "Do the people of Korea want the division to continue?" As if everywhere in the world simply the will of the people would happen...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- The government of the Democratic People's Republic of Korea (DPRK, North Korea) wants reunification on their terms, i.e. the rule of the Kim dynasty over the entire peninsula under the [Juche](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juche) system. The people of the People's Republic are not consulted.
- The people and government of the Republic of Korea (ROK, South Korea) mostly want reunification on their terms, i.e. a multi-party parliamentary system for the entire peninsula. Some might have doubt about extending capitalism and democracy too fast, some might put unification over democracy.
- The DPRK did not collapse the way the GDR (East Germany) did when Soviet/Warsaw Pact/COMECON system collapsed. Part of that was due to a lesser integration into the Soviet system, another part was that the DPRK government *decided* to hold out. The result was the economic downturn and famine called the [Arduous March](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Korean_famine).

The GDR  government *might* have ordered their troops to shoot at the citizens. The troops *might* have followed that order. They didn't give the order and the Berlin Wall collapsed.

Comment: North Korea would not fall as China didn't fall.

Comment: In case of GDR, it _might_ have helped that Gorbachev openly said that the Soviet forces would not interfere. There was a brief moment in 1988-9 when the USSR felt more open and free than Honecker's GDR. This is relevant because (with the ref. to the above @CleverTP's comment) China actively doesn't want reunification. While there is no particular love for DPRK, China understands that reunification can only happen on SK terms, and that would mean US's presence on their border, etc.

Answer (score 5):

First it a bit incorrect to call Korea the only divisions created by the Cold War still existing, an other example would be China and Taiwan.

To understand why there is a difference to other examples, we need to look how other divisions have ended. All other divisions have ended with some kind of annexation of one part by an other. While in Germany the annexation was peaceful, so some would disagree with using this term, in Vietnam it was really bloody. The Vietnam solution hasn´t work in Korea as none of the sites was able to conquer another by force. For the solution like in Germany there need to be a regime collapse in one of the parts and even such collapse is not a guaranty for reunification as the regime in South Korea has already collapsed in the 80s but has not lead to reunification.

Comment: The division between Taiwan and the PRC was not created by the Cold War.  Although Taiwan was part of the Japanese empire in the 1920s when the Chinese Civil War started, at the end of WWII Taiwan was placed under the control of one of the Chinese Civil War's belligerents, the one that went on to lose the civil war just 4 years later and retreat to Taiwan.  It is thus the Chinese Civil War that recreated the separation that had started in 1895.

Comment: @Readin Shure the civil war in China started long befor the Cold War, but the division was during the Cold War and every side was suported by one of the superpowers.

Answer (score 3):

Sovereign states have a tendency to *keep going* - once a country exists and is recognized, it is becoming full of its own elites, government officials, state intellectuals - some of whom risk losing their status in case of a merger with another country, which has a set of their own.

This does not fully explain why e.g. corporations are much more eager to merge than countries. But the observation is there.

North Koreans realistically wanted an "one country, two systems" merge with South Korea but it was not possible either politically or economically. They have a border with a largest difference of wealth in a whole world, I believe. And Kim family who want to keep their kingdom really bad.

Comment: Corporations frequently merge through a buyout of one of the corporation's shares by the other corporation.

Comment: @ohwilleke But countries normaly work diferently then corporations.

Answer (score 3):

Because the [Korean War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_War#Division_of_Korea_(1954%E2%80%93present)) is still ongoing. The [Korean Armistice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_Armistice_Agreement) is *only* between North Korea and China on the one side, and the United Nations on the other side. South Korea never signed this agreement, hence North Korea and South Korea are technically still at war.

Comment: This answer just dodges the actual question: Why are North and South Korea *still* technically at war for 70 years? Why does the division continue for such a long time?

Comment: I beg to disgree. The Koreas are technically still at war, hence there can be no reunification. The OP asked "Why are there still 2 Koreas?", well none of them won/lost the war. As to why they are still at war, that's a different question.

Comment: If that's really the only reason why a Korean unification is currently impossible, then the question why there is the political will to keep a cold war active for almost 70 years is *exactly* the question.